# Can I query for an optional field in the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graphql

I have OAuth2 access tokens for both Users and Facebook Pages but I don't have the type distinction stored in my database. I'd like to be able to fetch basic information about the User/Page using the very same Graph API query - but for users, I'd like to get email field on top of that.

1. `GET v2.5/me?fields=name,email` // User token

   Success.
2. `GET v2.5/me?fields=name,email` // Page token

   **Error.** `(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (email) on node type (Page)`

Since I don't know if the token belongs to User or Page, I can't remove the `,email` field from the query easily. Is there any way how to specify "optional" `email` field, so I don't get the above error?

P.S.: Currently, I do second request in case of `,email` cause the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the API will fail if you request fields which don't exist on the type of object you're requesting - if it didn't [and it didn't until relatively recently], there's a whole class of bugs which introduced by people requesting non existent fields, including via typos

If you don't know what type of object an ID is when you go to access it, there's probably some other issue with how your app retrieves and stores its data - for this example, you should use the metadata (`?metadata=true`) or [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to clean up which tokens are user tokens and which are page tokens and which page or user they're for - once you know, store that info, and use that in future -
If using the API directly and checking the metadata, check the `type` in the response when metadata is included, it will be 'user' or 'page' for user or page tokens

Your app really shouldn't have page tokens saved but not know which page they're for because you needed the user access token for a page admin in order to retrieve that token from the API; I'd recommend storing the user token and page token in a structured way when you first save the page token to avoid this confusion in future